# Objective c-[ERROR] DBRequest#connectionDidFinishLoading: error moving temp file to desired location:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova

Error and warning shown when trying to download a file from dropbox app folder to iphone.This is my code

```
-(void) download:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
   { 
 CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

NSLog(@"Dropbox restore method is executing");

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,         NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory

NSString *localPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"key.txt"];

NSString *dropBoxFile = @"/key.txt";

[[self restClient]  loadFile:dropBoxFile intoPath:localPath];

 pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];

 self.restoreJavaScript = [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:command.callbackId];
 }
```

error details:[ERROR] DBRequest#connectionDidFinishLoading: error moving temp file to desired location: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)

Warning:[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files/sandbox/key.txt - (512) Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)"

Can anyone figure out whats wrong!!! :(

Comment: Try to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13675110/2941357

Comment: Thanks for the help :) My program ran successfully without making any changes in it, the next day of the error.

Comment: I get this problem intermittently (ONLY on hardware, not simulator)- so just because it appears to work the following day, does not mean its solved.

Comment: I donot know about that,but i haven't got such error after that and its working successfully.:)@PeterJohnson